# Localhost not open on Expo start command

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, localhost

when I run the command expo start its open me on the terminal the QR code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnrGI.png)
and when scan the code its open me on the phone this unload page:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PX7W1.jpg)
this happen only when I in my mom's house in my apartment its open me this page:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VP2Ku.jpg)
so I think its should be problem on the internet, if someone know to explain how to allow in the setting its will really help, thanks!

Comment: have you used ExpoGo app to scan QR code ?

Comment: of course , its open when I work in my apartment but when i try to open it in my mom house this what happened a page that not load up.

Comment: believe you are suppose to open on your computer browser. Then enter whether you emulating to the web, mobile, etc. If you have a phone connected to the computer then via adb it should connect and render. Though, if you don't have a phone it uses an emulator based on the option you entered to render the application in Android or iOS.

Comment: yes this is another problem that only the QR CODE open on the terminal and not open automatically like its should , I try to use real phone and I say again in my apartment its work fine only here not...